# Can't launch Spring Boot 2x application from start.spring.io

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When i try to launch spring boot application i get NoClassDefFoundError exception. afaik it's a dependency problem, but i can't resolve it.

Here is stacktrace:

```
2017-11-30 17:57:38.357  WARN 15623 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatServletWebServerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'serverPropertiesWebServerFactoryCustomizer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'serverPropertiesWebServerFactoryCustomizer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'server-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl
2017-11-30 17:57:38.361  INFO 15623 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-11-30 17:57:38.376 ERROR 15623 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatServletWebServerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'serverPropertiesWebServerFactoryCustomizer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'serverPropertiesWebServerFactoryCustomizer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'server-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:153) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:138) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:751) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:387) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1245) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1233) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    at com.example.demo7.Demo7Application.main(Demo7Application.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatServletWebServerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'serverPropertiesWebServerFactoryCustomizer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'serverPropertiesWebServerFactoryCustomizer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'server-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:591) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getWebServerFactory(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:212) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:176) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:150) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'serverPropertiesWebServerFactoryCustomizer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'serverPropertiesWebServerFactoryCustomizer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'server-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:729) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:470) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1250) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerFactoryCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.getWebServerFactoryCustomizerBeans(WebServerFactoryCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:126) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerFactoryCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.getCustomizers(WebServerFactoryCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:116) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerFactoryCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(WebServerFactoryCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:76) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerFactoryCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(WebServerFactoryCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:64) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:423) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1702) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'server-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:591) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:815) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:721) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ConfigurationImpl
    at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.createGenericConfiguration(HibernateValidator.java:33) ~[hibernate-validator-6.0.5.Final.jar:6.0.5.Final]
    at javax.validation.Validation$GenericBootstrapImpl.configure(Validation.java:296) ~[validation-api-2.0.0.Final.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.validation.MessageInterpolatorFactory.getObject(MessageInterpolatorFactory.java:53) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ValidatedLocalValidatorFactoryBean.<init>(ValidatedLocalValidatorFactoryBean.java:35) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBinderBuilder.determineValidator(ConfigurationPropertiesBinderBuilder.java:150) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBinderBuilder.build(ConfigurationPropertiesBinderBuilder.java:137) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.getBinder(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:196) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:167) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:423) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1702) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583) ~[spring-beans-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    ... 43 common frames omitted
```

And it's a pom.xml. No changed was maded - originally generated project from start.spring.io

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo7</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo7</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.M7</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>


</project>
```

Application code is just run spring application:

```
package com.example.demo7;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Demo7Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Demo7Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

This problem is only with Boot 2x, 1.5 is working fine and i can't find similar problem with google.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your code cannot find some Hibernate classes. Try importing them yourself in your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.5.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

A similar issue was solved on [another platform](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring/spring-mvc/solved-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initialize-class-org-hibernate-validator-engine-configurationimpl/), if you want to check.

Comment: In pom.xml there are already some hibernate dependencies like:
<dependency><groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId><artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId><exclusions><exclusion><groupId>org.hibernate</groupId><artifactId>hibernate core</artifactId></exclusion></exclusions></dependency><dependency><groupId>org.hibernate</groupId><artifactId>hibernate-hikaricp</artifactId><exclusions><exclusion><groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId><artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId></exclusion><exclusion><groupId>org.hibernate</groupId><artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId></exclusion></exclusions></dependency>

Comment: Addition to comment above: but also this part:
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-hikaricp</artifactId>
        </dependency>

Should I still add this hibernate validator and leave the existing dependencies?